# Laravel 5 Eloquent charset utf8 issues

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, utf-8, eloquent

I use Laravel 5.1 and a mysql server.
I have a database with table in utf8 unicode, and my databse configuration file is like this :

```
'mysql' => array(
'driver'    => 'mysql',
'host'      => 'localhost',
'database'  => 'database',
'username'  => 'root',
'password'  => 'password',
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix'    => 'false',
),
```

But when I use queries from eloquent, my texts which have accents are broken. It's not a problem from blade because I can write accent in the views correctly, and if I use PDO directly my text is nice.

How can I solve my problem with my queries from eloquent ?

Comment: Check your files' encoding. You're probably mixing them wrong.

Comment: @charlesrockbass The question clearly states that writing directly in the view works, and that the data comes from the database. File encoding won't matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my problem, I hope it will help others :

My Mysql databases are encoded in latin1 by default. I was sure that my databases were in utf8 so I configured as that in the configuration file on my laravel project.

Comment: This sure helped me - You should accept this as the answer!